# Travis CI fails with support dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, travis-ci

I have a project with two modules.
The first module (the library module) has these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
}
```

The second module (the app module) has these ones:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile project(":library-module-above")
}
```

This is my *.travis.yml* file:

```
language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8

android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - build-tools-25.0.2
    - android-25
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-support

branches:
  only:
    - master

script:
  - ./gradlew build connectedCheck --stacktrace

before_cache:
  - rm -f  $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
  - rm -fr $HOME/.gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/

cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
    - $HOME/.android/build-cache
```

The build on Travis fails because it cannot find support apis (`RecyclerView`, `LayoutManager`, support annotations).

If I run the same command (`./gradlew build connectedCheck --stacktrace`) on my local machine, the build passes with 0 errors finding all symbols.

Are my Travis components corrects? Or there's something else I've missed?

**EDIT**

The errors about "cannot find symbols" didn't stop the build.
I've didn't notice the error about licenses:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2, Android SDK Platform 25].
```

I wrote the solution in the answers.

Comment: Please post the exact error messages from the Travis CI log.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I found the solution on Travis official Github page, so I added an answer with those references. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You should still edit your question with the error messages to make this more useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it adding another `tools` component.
I found the solution on the official Travis Github's page.

Here: https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/issues/779

And here: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6801

My final `.travis.yml` components are:

```
components:
  - tools
  - platform-tools
  - tools # used above api 25.x
  - build-tools-25.0.2
  - android-25
  - extra-android-support
  - extra-android-m2repository
  - extra-google-m2repository
```

Now everything works correctly.

Comment: You have `tools` listed twice.  Is that deliberate?

Comment: @Armand Yes, it was an issue that you can find on the Github page of Travis